# Gulp, Moustache. How to concat data with src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, internationalization, rendering

I'm using the *[gulp-html-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-i18n)* gulp plugin for handling the translations task in a static website.

In order to display the translated content, I should use the *[Moustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)* lib as **gulp-html-i18n** mentioned in his [*doc*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-i18n).

I'm facing difficulties in the concatenation operations. For example, if I need to assign a conditional class for a html element, I will use the following flow:

```
${{! if}}$
 ${{#index.isEnglish}}$
<body class="en">
 ${{/index.isEnglish}}$
${{! else}}$
 ${{^index.isEnglish}}$
<body class="sp">
 ${{/index.isEnglish}}$
```

In the code above, I'm checking if the language is English, for example,  then the class is assigned based on the *isEnglish* value.

By this approach, we will face a big problem if I need to add new language also it's long and not comprehensive.

Moreover, let suppose I have an array of objects in the following interface:

```
"data":[{
 "title": "foo",
 "description": "bar",
 "icon": "iconname"
},...]
```

What if I need to concat the icon name with the *scr* attribute path while looping through the array above?

```
<div class="content">
    ${{#index.home.services.data}}$
    <h3>
        ${{title}}$
    </h3>
    <p>
        ${{description}}$
    </p>
    <img src="path/${{}}$.png" alt=""> ---> Not working with Moustache
    ${{/index.home.services.data}}$
</div>
```

So how can I solve the problems above? and what is the best practices for the Moustache.js concatenations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sloved!**

Solved by using scripts of type *text/template*.

We can't do the concatition operator directly inside a html attribute, We should write it inside a script of type *text/template*. like the following example:

```
<script type="text/template" id="header">
    ${{#index.pages}}$
    <button>
        <a href="./${{fileName}}$"></a>
        ${{title}}$
    </button>
    ${{/index.pages}}$
</script>
```

Then render the script content and assign it to specific html element using the following javascript code:

```
var headerTemplate = $('#header').html();
var headerHtml = Mustache.to_html(headerTemplate);
$('#navBar').html(headerHtml);
```

> Note: The dollar signs are used based on gulp plugin for localization task [gulp-html-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-i18n)
>    in order to link the json file to mustache.

If I'm not using the mentioned plugin I must update my code to  become:

```
var headerTemplate = $('#header').html();
var headerHtml = Mustache.to_html(headerTemplate,'path to data');
$('#navBar').html(headerHtml);
```

One of the most helpful link [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/).